# Maximization of the Expectation of a function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, expectation, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Recently I was thinking in general on how to maximize the expectation of a function (not necessarily a utility function, but apparently this is a common case). To give an idea of the kind of problem, here there is a possible setting.

- $F (x, y, z, k)$ integrable function
- $y := \phi (z, k)$
- $x \in [0,1]$
- $k \in K$.

$$ \max_{x} \int_{K} F (x, y, z, k) \ dk.$$

Now, how do we deal with a problem like this one?

I thought that maybe Calculus of Variations (or optimal control theory) should be the thing. However, looking on the Internet I found a question named ["Maximizing Expected Utility"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208939/maximizing-expected-utility) on MO, where a user answers that not necessarily we have to use calculus of variations for maximizing expected utility.

---

**QUESTIONS:**

1) *How do we deal with a problem like this one?*

2) *How do we deal with this problem **without** using the Calculus of Variations?*

---

Is there somebdoy that can shed some light on it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: in your example, I think the result of the integral is independent of $k$.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I messed the text with plenty of typos. Now, it should be more in line with what I had in mind.